# One to many relationships in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to create an item table  and an order table where an order can have many items, but an item can belong to only one order. What is missing in my code?

```
create table items (
    id serial primary key unique ,
    product_name varchar(500) not null unique,
    price int not null 
)

create table product_orders (
    order_id serial primary key unique,
    customer_name varchar(500),
    fk_price INT REFERENCES items(price)
)
```

tried adding the foreign key keyword

Comment: When items refer to an order, you need the `order_id` in the items table.   Optionally you can create a foreign key, see => docs, because I never used those things.   (docs: [PostgreSQL Foreign Key](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-foreign-key/))

Comment: Price as FK makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the primary key is always called `id`. One-to-many relationships are created by having a reference from the child record to the parent.

```
create table product_orders (
    id serial primary key unique,
    customer_name varchar(500)
);

create table items (
    id serial primary key unique ,
    order_id serial references product_orders(id),
    product_name varchar(500) not null unique,
    price int not null 
)
```

Comment: I mostly agree with calling the primary key `id` (table-level namespace) instead of `ìtem_id` (schema-level namespace), since it's makes things much simpler from the programming point of view, but I can see the schema-level namespace can have a point in some really complex schemas.

Comment: This is correct, but I would remove `unique` after `primary key`. Also, nowadays `serial` is being deprecated in favor of `identity by default`. +1